# Decoupled CMS, Selective crawling of the db server

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, robots.txt

We are running a decoupled CMS (using Wordpress as our db) and want to prevent search engines from crawling our posts from this server. We have post templates on that server so writers can preview their posts and Google has found them.

Am I able to detect a that a crawler is trying to access these pages in my .htaccess file and redirect to the www server? Is redirecting the wrong solution here? Can robots.txt block a generic pattern such as category/post-title?

Three things need to still happen:

1. We need to still be able to access db.site.com/wp-admin
2. Writers still need to preview their posts, which means they cannot be redirected.
3. db.site.com/wp-content/uploads needs to be accessible so Social sites can pull
   images.

Here are how the posts are setup. Basically I want to block or redirect posts from db.site.com

```
db.site.com/category/post-title

www.site.com/category/post-title
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have some code (in a shared section on each pages) to redirect the user to the main page if the user is not logged in with a valid account?

Comment: That may work. Another thing I just thought of is add .html to the article urls on the db.site.com so I can easily use robots to block any url ending in .html